# Is there a way to Refresh the View if i sent Data to a Server in NativeScript?

Tags: angular, nativescript

So, I Am using NativeScript and I have a List in a Page (Not a ListView) and this List Contains Data from the Server.

Example:

A.1 Bread

A.2 Paper

under the List i can put new items in this list by sending it to the server after a alert pops up. I want, when the user presses Ok at the alert, that the page refreshes so the new item is visible in the List.

A.1 Bread
A.2 Paper

Pen
Add</Button

Alert "New Item is added!" --> Ok

**New List:**

**A.1 Bread**

**A.2 Paper**

**A.3 Pen**

[This is how my list looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiPev.png)

[this is how they look like when an item is collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAJ0P.png)

I hav a textfield and button, that lets you add an new item and the details are calculated by a function. i just need the list to automatically refresh when the button is tapped and the data is written in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using ListView, what are you using?  Typically, the view's refresh() method is called when new data needs to be rendered.

Comment: I did my own List, because i need the Listitems to collapse and show more details. Listview only opens another frame, what i didnt want. I will edit a photo of my created list.